# How do I add a row of data to a spreadsheet stored in a python variable?

Tags: python, google-sheets, streamlit

I'm using streamlit and this [Gsheets connection](https://github.com/streamlit/gsheets-connection) library to load a google spreadsheet into a variable. I want to add a row to the spreadsheet.

The intention of my code is to get input from a user (Employee) and store the data in a google sheets document which is managed by the employer. Ideally I want to be able to append the user input to the spreadsheet.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from datetime import datetime
from streamlit_gsheets import GSheetsConnection


# title for the web page
st.title("Office Seat Booking System")

# Input fields for Employee ID, Floor, and Date
employee_id = st.text_input("Employee ID")
floor = st.selectbox("Floor", ["Floor 1", "Floor 2"])
date = st.date_input("Date")

# Establishing a Google Sheets connection
conn = st.experimental_connection("gsheets", type=GSheetsConnection)


#Existing Seats into a Datafram
st.write("Existing seats")
existing_entries = conn.read(worksheet="Bookings")

creating seat entry
 current_seat = {
     'Timestamp': [datetime.now()],
     'Employee_ID': [employee_id],
     'Floor': [floor],
    'Date': [date]
 }

st.write("New seats")
st.dataframe(current_seat)

# Submit button
if st.button("Submit"):
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    # updated_seats = pd.concat([existing_entries,current_seat]).drop_duplicates()
    #updated_seats = existing_entries.add_row(data=current_seat)
    #updated_seats = existing_entries.update(current_seat)
    updated_seats = existing_entries | current_seat    
    bookit = conn.update(worksheet="Bookings", data=current_seat)
    st.success(f"Your Seat has been booked  {timestamp}")
```

Since this library doesn't provide a way to update a single row (or maybe I don't know how) I'm trying to concatenate the row (as a dataframe) with  the sheets data but it is giving me the following error

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 541, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\office-seat-booking\connect-streamlit-with-google-sheets\bookseats.py", line 47, in <module>
    updated_seats = existing_entries | current_seat
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 72, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 80, in __or__
    return self._logical_method(other, operator.or_)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7592, in _arith_method
    self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=True, level=None)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 282, in align_method_FRAME
    right = to_series(right)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 239, in to_series
    raise ValueError(
```

I want to append the entered data to the google spreadsheet.

The update function provided by the library replaces all the data in the google spreadsheet but it is able to read all the data from the spreadsheet. I'm trying to concatenate entire excel spreadsheet data with the new row and then update the google spreadsheet with this new concatenated data.